# Why are transparent table tennis balls not used?

Tags: equipment, table-tennis

Transparent table tennis balls are less visible and would be suitable for training purposes; the eyes require more effort to catch the ball.

Transparent means that they are not opaque or a cloudy color. However I have not seen anybody that uses them, nor could I find a producer or distributor.

Why are transparent table tennis balls not used or not available?

Comment: Making the ball harder to see may improve a skill of detecting the ball but I don't think competitors have any trouble detecting where the ball is,. The difficulty is in anticipating the trajectory of the ball, before and after the bounce. It's a question of reaction time, not acuity. What about balls that travel faster than normal (not too sure if need to be lighter or heavier), or maybe smaller balls.

Answer (score 1):

According to the ITTF regulations, table tennis balls must be made of celluloid or a similar material and be white or orange in color.

This is because the color and material of the ball affect its visibility, and using transparent balls could potentially result in visibility issues, making it difficult for players and officials to track the ball's movement during the game.

Transparent balls may also be harder to see against certain backgrounds or lighting conditions, which could impact the fairness of the game.

Comment: Training equipment does not need to follow any game-play rule or regulation, and if the entire purpose of using a transparent ball for training is precisely because it's harder to see, this post does not appear to be relevant as an answer.

Comment: I can't find any point in using a transparent ball. Using the same ball used in the official game is very natural. Using a different ball in the training would make players feel uncomfortable in the real game.

Comment: It sounds like you speak from an assumption rather than experience on that point. Using nonstandard equipment in training is fairly regular in other sports, for particular skills development, is there a specific reason you believe it does not and would not ever apply in table tennis?